# PowerShell script to create Excel spreadsheet from HTML file

Tags: html, excel, powershell

This script is designed to create an Excel spreadsheet from each HTML table from auto-generated `index.html` file.

It needs to be very robust but unfortunately I don't have many example files to test it against. Any feedback on style, possible points of failure, or vulnerabilities would be very appreciated.

#### Powershell

```
function Main
{

    # find each file called "index.html" in the folders below the directory of the script
    $Directory = $PSScriptRoot
    $htmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -path $Directory -Recurse -Include index.html

    # for each html file, create an excel file in the directory of the script
    # called Exceptions Log <date of HTML file creation>.xlsx
    ForEach($htmlFile in $htmlFiles)
    {
        $fileCreationDate = (Get-ChildItem $htmlFile).CreationTime
        $fileString = $fileCreationDate.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss")
        $outputFile = "$Directory\Exceptions Log $fileString.xlsx"

        Write-Host "Parsing HTML file: $htmlFile"
        $document = ParseHtml $htmlFile

        Write-Host "Creating Excel file: $outputFile"
        CreateExcelFromHtml $document $outputFile
    }

}


# load local HTML file and return COM object that we can query
function ParseHtml([string]$fileIn)
{
    $html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
    $source = Get-Content $fileIn -Raw
    $html.IHTMLDocument2_write($source)
    return $html
}


# create excel spreadsheet from html document
function CreateExcelFromHtml($document, [string]$excelFile)
{    
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application    
    $excel.Visible = $false # $true
    $excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()    
    $sheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet

    Write-Host "Filling in Excel file"
    $row = 1;
    # iterate over tables
    $tables = $document.getElementsByTagName("table")
    $captions = $document.getElementsByTagName("caption")

    for($t=0; $t -lt $tables.length; $t++){

        # create 2 row space between tables
        $row += 2

        #iterate over rows
        $rows = $tables[$t].getElementsByTagName("tr") 
        for($i=0; $i -lt $rows.length; $i++)
        {

            # iterate over cells
            # every other cell is a blank cell, however cells with content are always nested in a "font" tag     
            $cells = $rows[$i].getElementsByTagName("font") 
            for($j=0; $j -lt $cells.length; $j++)
            {
                # load each cell contents into an excel cell
                $sheet.Cells.Item($row + $i, $j+1) = $cells[$j].innerText.Trim()
            }
        }

        # add corrective action column to first table
        if($t -eq 0){ 
            $j += 1 # increment table size
            $sheet.Cells.Item($row, $j) = "Corrective Action"; 
        }

        # get table title from corresponding caption
        $title = [string]$captions[$t].innerText

        StyleTable $sheet $title $row $i $j

        $row += $i

    }

    Write-Host "Formating Excel file"
    $sheet.UsedRange.ColumnWidth = 18

    Write-Host "Saving Excel file"
    $workbook.SaveAs($excelFile, 51)
    $workbook.Close();
    $excel.Quit()

}


Function StyleTable($sheet, $tableTitle, $startRow, $numberOfRows, $endColumn){

    # give the table a title and style it
    $titleCell = $sheet.Cells($startRow - 1, 1)
    $titleCell.Value = $tableTitle   
    $titleCell.Font.Name = "Cambria"
    $titleCell.Font.Size = 14
    $titleCell.Font.Bold = $true
    $titleCell.Font.ThemeColor = 5

    # give the table a border 
    $tableRange = $sheet.Range($sheet.Cells($startRow, 1), ` 
        $sheet.Cells($startRow + $numberOfRows - 1, $endColumn)) 

    $tableRange.Borders.Weight = 2

    # make the table header bold and blue
    $headerRange = $sheet.Range($sheet.Cells($startRow, 1), `
        $sheet.Cells($startRow, $endColumn))

    $headerRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    $headerRange.Font.Bold = $true
}


Main
```

#### Example `index.html` file

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
> <title>FooBar</title>
> </head>
>
> <body>
> <center>
> <p>
> <b><font size=6>Bar</font>
> </b><br>
> <b><font size=4>Foo</font>
> </b><br>
> <font size=3>FooBar</font>
> </p>
>
> <table>
> <caption><font size=3><b>Title</b></font></caption>
> <thead>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>A</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>B</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>C</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>D</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>E</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>F</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>G</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> </thead>
>
> <tbody>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>1</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>2</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>3</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>4</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>5</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>6</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>7</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Do</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Re</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Mi</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Fa</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>So</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>La</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Ti</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Do</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Re</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Mi</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Fa</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>So</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>La</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Ti</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Do</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Re</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Mi</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Fa</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>So</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>La</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Ti</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Do</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Re</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Mi</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Fa</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>So</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>La</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Ti</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Do</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Re</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Mi</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Fa</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>So</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>La</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Ti</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Do</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Re</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Mi</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Fa</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>So</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>La</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Ti</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Do</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Re</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Mi</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Fa</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>So</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>La</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Ti</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Do</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Re</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Mi</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Fa</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>So</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>La</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Ti</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Do</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Re</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Mi</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Fa</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>So</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>La</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Ti</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Do</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Re</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Mi</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Fa</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>So</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>La</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Ti</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> </tbody>
> </table>
>
> <br>
> <table>
> <caption><font size=3><b>Title 2</b></font></caption>
> <thead>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>Foo</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>Bar</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>FoobBar</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> </thead>
>
> <tbody>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Fizz</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Buzz</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>FizzBuzz<br>
> &nbsp;<br>
> &nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Foo</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Bar</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>FooBar<br>
> &nbsp;<br>
> &nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> </tbody>
> </table>
>
> <br>
> <table>
> <caption><font size=3><b>Title 3</b></font></caption>
> <thead>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>Fizz</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>Buzz</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>FizzBuzz</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>FooBar</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> </thead>
>
> <tbody>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Foo</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Bar</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>FooBar</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>FizzBuzz</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> </tbody>
> </table>
>
> <br>
> <p>
> <b><font size=4>Something</font>
> </b><br>
> </p>
>
> <table>
> <caption><font size=3><b>Title 4</b></font></caption>
> <thead>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>Foo</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>Bar</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>Fizz</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> <th align=left valign=bottom><font size=2><u>Buzz</u></font></th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
> </thead>
>
> <tbody>
> <tr>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Foo</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Bar</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Fizz</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Buzz</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> <tr>
> <b><td valign=top><font size=2>Foo</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </b><td valign=top><font size=2>Bar</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Fizz</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> <td valign=top><font size=2>Buzz</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
> </tr>
>
> </tbody>
> </table>
>
> <br>
> </center>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

#### Output

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your code looks fine. Just some notes:

## Excel

The main weakness of your design as I see it is its reliance on the Excel application. Since you say robustness is important, Excel would be the main weak point. Microsoft says [don't use Office as a server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757). From my own bitter experience, I think they are right to say that.

It's not so bad in your case because you are doing the same thing over and over, so there should be no surprises, but you never know. Excel can be flakey. It can pop up dialogs that will halt processing. It's especially flakey if you are processing multiple documents simultaneously because Excel was never designed to handle that case.

As an alternative, you could use a library to produce your Excel, such as [EPPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/). I've never used that, so I can't endorse it, but it looks good. There may be others out there too. Remember that it's easy to use .Net libraries from PowerShell.

## HTML

Your HTML is very nearly XHTML. It looks like just the `<br>` tags would need to be fixed. If you have control over the thing that produces the HTML, then you could change it to produce XHTML instead, and then you could consume that with `Import-XML`. I'm guessing that's not the case, but I thought it worth mentioning.

## Error Handling

You don't have any error handling. If you want your code to be robust you will have to think about what it should do when things go wrong.

## Write-Host

```
Write-Host "Formating Excel file"
```

If you want to capture these messages in a log, then it would be better to use `Write-Output`.

## Line Continuation

```
$tableRange = $sheet.Range($sheet.Cells($startRow, 1), ` 
    $sheet.Cells($startRow + $numberOfRows - 1, $endColumn))
```

I don't believe you need to use the backtick character there.

## -Include

```
$htmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -path $Directory -Recurse -Include index.html
```

One oddity of PowerShell is that `-Filter` is much faster than `-Include`. If the number of folders and files you are searching is small, then it doesn't matter, but if you are searching through lots of them, it can make a huge difference.

(What is the difference in functionality between the two? None, except that `-Include` is more general and will work in non-filesystems, but that isn't relevant here.)

Comment: There is no `Import-Xml`. The only close alternative it `Import-CliXml`, and that doesn't work like you'd expect. Instead you have to do something like this: `[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path C:\Cars.xml` after which u can use it like objects. See [here](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-read-xml-files,2-895.html).

Comment: @Adamar, yes, sorry, that's what I meant. XML is a native datatype in PowerShell. Once you cast to an [xml] object, you can pipe that through `Select-Xml` and use XPath expressions to extract the data you want. My point was simply that working with XML may be more straightforward than working with HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler approach.  Excel has native HTML conversion capabilities that work fine.  Using the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.applicationclass?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=excel-pia) in powershell:

```
function SaveAs-Excel2010{
    param([string] $infile, [string] $outfile, [string] $tabname = $null)

    $Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
    $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($infile) 

    if ($tabname) {
        $Sheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)       
        $Sheet.Name = $tabname;
    }
    $Workbook.SaveAs($outfile, $xlFixedFormat) 
    $Workbook.Close()
    $Excel.quit()
}  

#sample call
SaveAs-Excel2010 $htmlFile $xlsxFile $myTabName
```